# arduino EM408 GPS problem

Tags: serial

I have written this little snippet of code to interface with EM408 GPS.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial GPS = SoftwareSerial(2,3);  //rx,tx
void setup()
{
  GPS.begin(4800);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  //Serial.print(GPS.read(), BYTE);
  Serial.write(byte(GPS.read()));  //as of Arduino 1.0
}
```

Hardware side i have these connections: 
ENABLE: 3.3V 
Vcc   : 3.3V 
Ground: Ground 
Rx, Tx correctly connected to arduino and correctly initialized with SoftwareSerial

However, the values i get are just junk data

```
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

I get these without ending...
I experimenting with changing the baud rate, still the same thing goes on.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
I used to get random junk data before with the EM406 gps module, but i solved it by casting everything to BYTE. I have tried both approaches here, but the results are the same...

Comment: what about `Serial.write((byte)(GPS.read()));`?

Comment: just the same result....

Comment: related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110699/gps-sensor-serial-monitor-output

Comment: The datasheet indicates that the communications port is "TTL Levels", which usually means that the data is inverted relative to normal RS-232 levels.  If you are connecting to a true RS-232 port on the Arduino, you will need to invert the signals to/from the GPS module.

Comment: What Arduino model do you use?

Comment: Duemilanove with 328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you get is that `read()` does not wait for a byte to be available, it just returns `-1` if there is no byte available; converted as an unsigned byte that becomes `255`.

In **ISO-8859-1**, which I guess is the encoding that your serial monitor is using, `255` translates to `ÿ`, so this is exactly what you observe.

Fixing this problem is straightforward, just check that a byte is available on `SoftwareSerial` before reading it:

```
void loop()
{
    if (GPS.available()) {
        Serial.write(byte(GPS.read()));  //as of Arduino 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this method, i receive nothing at all, with all baud rates combination and independent of time passed...

Comment: If you receive nothing, that may come from your wiring: voltage level, crossed connections, short-circuit...

Comment: Note that in your current code, you don't receive either, as I have explained, if `ÿ` is the only thing you get, it means your `GPS` stream never receives anything...